# Prevent "title" attribute of parent element from causing a browser flyover

Tags: javascript, html, title

The good browsers all work such that an empty "title" attribute for an element means, "don't bother to show a title flyover here".  That makes sense, as a little white flyover with nothing in it (**edit** — or nothing but a space character) is, for most people, completely useless.

The designers of IE do not agree.

My problem is that I've got a little "what's this?" mechanism on a site that involves an absolutely-positioned `<div>` containing a little graphic of a question mark. That `<div>` has a "title" attribute with a question like, "What does the 'History Eraser Button' do?"  When you click on the question mark, a little "Help" bubble pops out and you can read about the topic. The idea of the "title" is that if the user mouses over the question mark, they see a question that's (hopefully) one they might be wondering about.

Well the problem with the "title" is that the pop-out "help" balloon is inside the absolutely-positioned `<div>` so that it is correctly situated on the page. In other words, the absolutely-positioned `<div>` just has "position: absolute", but it's allowed to be dropped on the page in the "right" place without any offset computation. The "help" balloon is thus in the right place sort-of automatically.  **But**: that "title" on the parent `<div>` is pesky because the browser pops it up *after* the balloon is open. Why? because the "help" balloon is lexically contained in the outer `<div>`, even though the outer `<div>` is just a little bitty thing with a question mark in it.

Thus solution #1 was to give the "help" balloon `<div>` its *own* "title" attribute, with nothing in it (**edit** — I got that wrong; it's not *nothing* in the title, it's a space character). That works great, except in IE.  In IE now, that empty "title" attribute causes the browser to put up a little blank rectangle.  Helpful.

I could of course fiddle with the Javascript and just nuke the "title" attribute off the parent `<div>` while the balloon is showing, but I'm curious about possible ways to "override" the parent element "title" in IE that can be done with nothing but markup. If it's not possible, then oh well.

Simple demo page: http://gutfullofbeer.net/title.html (try it with IE 7 or 8 to see the little empty white box)

*edit* — ha ha ha - when I change my code so that I explicitly null out the "title" attributes on all the parent elements, IE shows a flyover with the word "null" in it :-)

Comment: I can set up a test page if you like; it's a pretty simple deal.

Comment: OK the question now includes the test page.

Comment: Can you just not include the title if there is none, or if it's blank, etc. on the server side?

Comment: Note that on your test page, I also see the "empty title" popup on Google Chrome 5 and Safari 5 (both on Mac).  IMO, this is the correct behavior - Firefox should be showing this too.

Comment: @Kyle Hi, and thanks. The issue is that I *want* the title on my little question mark thingy *when the help bubble isn't open*. After it's open, I don't care much about the help flyover on the little question mark, but I definitely don't want it over the help bubble because it's annoying and wrong there. I'll see if I can update my sample page to show the effect I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @desau well that's pretty interesting.  Thank you for noticing that!!  (wow, Chrome is pretty aggressive about tossing those flyover boxes up.)

Comment: Yes, they appear immediately.

Comment: Test page now updated with a little clickable thing that's more-or-less the setup I've got on my real site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up augmenting my existing code that opens/closes the "help" bubble so that it runs up the chain of parent elements and stashes the "title" code with the jQuery "data" facility. When the bubble closes, the titles are restored.

Answer (score 2):

Why not assign the title to the question mark element (#qmark) instead of the containing div?
So instead of:

```
<div title="this is the overlapping title">  
    <div id="qmark">?</div>
    <div id="hiddenContainer"></div>
</div>
```

it would be

```
<div>
    <div id="qmark" title="this title no longer overlaps">?</div> 
    <div id="hiddenContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a fine idea, and in fact I started doing that after reading @desau's answer. Then I realized that my "help" bubbles may actually nested inside *another* layer of "title"-bearing markup.  One might argue that I'm simply using too many of those and that I should get out of the habit, especially given the rise of "touch" interfaces where there's really no "hover" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want.  It seems like a hack anyway -- child DOM element attributes aren't meant to "override" parent attributes.  You should probably wrap the specific text with the correct title, such as this:

http://jsbin.com/ezipe

Comment: However, the "title" attribute in particular really can't work any other way.  It's not invalid by any definition I can think of for a container to have a different title than a contained element, and the browser is only ever going to show me one title, that being the one "closest" to the element over which the mouse is paused.